# Translate mat-tab with i18n

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using angular material tabs and I would like to know how could I translate the text of the tag using i18n. The structure of the tab is as follows:

```
<mat-tab-group class="group-tabs">
   <mat-tab label="Tab 1">
</mat-tab-group>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Something like this? `<mat-tab label="Tab 1" i18n-label>` [Mark element attributes for translations](https://angular.io/guide/i18n#mark-element-attributes-for-translations)

Answer (score 1):

Bringing a little bit more clarity to the response from Get Off My Lawn:

You can use the i18n-label to put in the translation tag, as such:

```
<mat-tab label="Tab 1" i18n-label="@@Tab 1 label"></mat-tab>
```

Then in your messages.xlf you can manage your translation.